# Script that removes the OneDrive icon from the Windows10 taskbar

Tags: powershell

This is my first post so I would like to say hello.

I need to disable the display of the icon from OneDrive, but so that the application still works only the icon was not on the taskbar.

In short, I need the OneDrive icon to disappear from this place:
[image]

I thought that the best solution would be to write a script in PowerShell that will be included when logging in, unfortunately I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: as far as i know you can't hide that icon from there without killing the application

Comment: According to the documentation the way to remove the system tray icon is to disable OneDrive. I don't think what you are trying to do is possible, it's not like you're just trying to delete a shortcut or something.